# Does class.getResource("." /*dot*/) have any special meaning?

Tags: java, classloader

Sometimes I see this in other people's code. But when I try, it returns null.

```
baseUrl = org.company.UploadService.class.getResource(".");
url = new URL(baseUrl, "http://192.168.164.32:9080/mka-web/services/UploadService?wsdl");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResource(".")` will, in some cases, return a URL pointing to the directory that class file is in.

[This thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1168163) describes the behaviour as:

> a URL pointing to the directory in the class path used to load the class if the class is loaded from a directory, or null when loaded from a jar.

The last part is likely why you're getting `null`. Another reason could be:

> It does not work with all JVMs

Answer (score 2):

Line `UploadService.class.getResource(".")` returns URL matches package of class `UploadServiece`, i.e. something like

`file://your-path/org/company` if you are running from file system
or
`jar:file://yourjar-path/org/company` if you are running from jar.

Constructor of `URL` that you are using returns the url in given context. For example

`new URL(new URL("http://google.com"), "yahoo.com")` returns `http://google.com/yahoo.com`, 
but
`new URL(new URL("http://google.com"), "http://yahoo.com")` returns `http://yahoo.com` because the second URL is absolute.

So, I your case the code does not make any sense: it is absolutely equialent to 
`new URL("http://192.168.164.32:9080/mka-web/services/UploadService?wsdl")`